# I'm too stupid to find any motorbike-related site on SE

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about my bike but I can't for my life locate any appropriate candidates. Henceforth, I declare myself too stupid to find it and I require assistance. My claim is based on the fact that I've found sites for *Aviation*, *Tor* and *Arduino*. And I **do know** that there's more people who can ride than who can fly. There are **two different** sites for the amazing Russian language for duck's sake (typo intended)!

Sorry for the ranty formulation - it's meant as a funny way to express my request and to ventilate my frustration at the same time. Also, please note that the bikes I'm referring to are those vroomy ones that are powered by giant, now-dead lizards and not the ecologically appropriate ones that are powered by foot sweat.

[image]

Comment: Those bikes?! I don't remember an SE proposal for Lizard-fuel bikes.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M I refuse to accept that there are more birds than bikers here (Aviation-site).

Comment: What about [mechanics.se]?

Comment: There are bikers here, but their foot is so sweaty their bikes don't run on lizard fuel.

Comment: @ChristianRau Not really bikes. More car aficionado site. But definitely closer than "English Lanugage Learners", hehe. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I always thought motorbikes are perfectly on-topic there, or am I mistaken? They aren't to blame for a mere lack of questions about motorbikes, though. If they're on-topic, they're on-topic. But maybe you might want to specify what the actual question is you want to ask. I'd wager that non-maintenance and repair stuff is very well off-topic there.

Comment: I can imagine such a site but there isn't even anything in Area51 ...

Comment: And frankly, that lizard thing *is* funny, but the *"ranty formulation"* is indeed more ranty than funny. ;-)

Comment: @ChristianRau Well, my question is about something that **might lead** to reparation so it's futuristically on-topic. As for the rantiness, if you refer to the word choice, please note that the birdy typo **is indeed** intended.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I write, there are [282 questions tagged "motorcycle" on the Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair site](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorcycle), so that's probably the site you want.

Comment: I'm inclined to admit that it's the right way to go. However, I'm still surprised by the low number. In my expectations, there'd be a site called *Motorbikes* and the tags *Honda* and *Varadero* would have 8000+ and 500+ hits respectively. What are all those Honda owners doing? Why aren't they in front of the computer discussing their bikes? Are they out riding them or what?!

Comment: There are also [bikes powered by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_motorcycles_and_scooters) your choice of supernatural being: [naiads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydropower), [cherubs with extreme lung capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_farm), [Morlock droppings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossil-fuel_power_station) or [Vishnu](http://blog.nuclearsecrecy.com/2014/05/23/oppenheimer-gita/). These are also on topic for MVMR, @KonradViltersten.